# Having trouble ensuring JavaScript events are triggered during Selenium scraping

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

**Process:** I am trying to scrape data within a [web page](https://doublethedonation.com/matching-gifts/walmart-stores-sams-club-executive-level-match). The process involves me inputting text in a search box, then selecting the top option from a dropdown -- selecting an option then triggers the data in the division to be updated and then I iterate through this process to collect the data for all inputs.

**Issue:** The drop down is not popping up when the text is input, and thus I can't update the data within the division I am scraping.

I see (using inspect element) that when I do the process manually, the name of the search input division class changes and a new division for the dropdown appears but this doesn't happen in the browser triggered by selenium. I've tried sending code to change the class name but this still doesn't trigger the dropdown.

Any insight on how I can trigger this JavaScript event?

Here's the code I have for this part of the scrape:

```
def search_for_company(driver, company_name):
    # find search input
    search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(config.SEARCH_INPUT_SELECTOR)
    search_box_div = search_input.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dd-container"]/div/div/div[3]')
    # Remove the readonly attribute
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", search_input)
    # clear the current text and update with new text
    search_input.clear()
    #search_input.send_keys(company_name)
    # you can see here I tried experimenting with trying to mimic actually user input, to no avail...
    for char in company_name:
        search_input.send_keys(char)
    # Change the class of the div
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'dtd-search-box is-open is-focused')", search_box_div)

    time.sleep(10)  # Allow time for potential results to load

    # Check if there are no results (skip if no dropdown results pop up)
    try:
        # this is an actual div class that pops up when there are no results
        no_results = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.dtd-noresults")
        if no_results.is_displayed():
            print("No results displayed >>> SKIPPED.")
            return False  # No results found
    except:
        # If no such element, proceed with pressing return
        search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(config.REQUEST_DELAY)
        print("Returning results.")
        return True  # Results found
```

Comment: you should include the markup of the page.  It sounds like you're targeting the wrong input.  (You shouldn't have to modify the DOM like you are doing here... like removing "readonly" and manually setting a style class)

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins, an example of the site I am trying to target is at this [link] (https://doublethedonation.com/matching-gifts/walmart-stores-sams-club-executive-level-match) here. The search input box is of class dtd-search -box. If you manually type something in here, you'll see a dropdown -- that is the event I am trying to trigger such that I can go from company to company. Appreciate the insight!